# Running Raspbian Jessie from SD in Mac OS

Tags: raspbian, wifi, macos

So, long story short, I've built a magic mirror for the lady, who lives abroad.

I've edited `wpa_supplicant` and added her wifi credentials, but when she got home, it won't connect to the internet.

I've figured the best way for her to get the Raspbian to connect would be to take the MicroSD out, and run it as a virtual machine in her Mac. If she can access the console, she could install `wicd-curses` and connect to her network.

My question is, how can she boot the Linux in her Macbook? Can she? At all?

Comment: No, she cannot.

Comment: She may however be able to mount and then read and write data to/from the microSD card's partitions in her Mac, which may or may not be of help to configure settings for the RPi... 8-)

Comment: Just realized it probably woud be easier to just buy a powered usb hub, and connect a keyboard and mouse to the raspberry and work directly on the running os..

Comment: If the default network/interfaces configuration is untouched and you have an ethernet socket then you should be able to get SSH access using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, she cannot (not sure about qemu and disk images though). Best bet would be to actually figure out what the problem is with the network and fix it. One benefit would be it would make future endeavors a bit more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to mount the Raspian Linux partition on the SD card from within OSX. Then the configuration can be altered directly on the card. It should be noted it takes a bit of setup to enable OSX to mount the ext4 filesystem as described in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x/162076), though this could be done if you've got remote access to the Mac - plus you'd need to know how to fix the problem with the config (as you still wouldn't be able to run wicd-curses). FYI if you have remote access you can do a command line WiFi scan on the Mac using the `airport` command so you can figure out what's different on her network:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -s
```